# Invocable method parameter value is null

Tags: visual-workflow, invocable-method

I am trying to run an scheduled flow which calls an invocable method.
Every time the method is called the parameter is showing as null. Any idea what could be the reason?

```
 public static void ParentAccountUpdate(List<String> accountIds) {

    System.debug('accountIds ' + accountIds);
    System.debug('accountIds size' + accountIds.size());

 }
```

Here is where i am passing the parameter in flow
[image]

Debug Logs

06:35:45.6 (6617597)|USER_DEBUG|[8]|DEBUG|accountIds (null)

06:35:45.6 (6661958)|USER_DEBUG|[9]|DEBUG|accountIds size1

Comment: is there any chance your flow is nulling out $Record.Id before it calls the invocable?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with your flow. Your query filter in your scheduled flow is not returning any records which is why the `$record` resource doesn't contain any records.

Comment: I am not sure if i understood it correctly. Are you saying the filter conditions on start are not returning any records? When do debug of the flow i can see that there is a account id which is been sent. I removed all the filters and tried same result

Comment: you can see in the debug in OP that accountIds.size() = 1 so the flow is calling the invocable for 1 record

Comment: @Prady please post your flow so we can continue to help. The issue is most likely with your flow since your invocable is working.